# How to combine an either does not exist and not matching in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to figure out how to tell mongodb to filter all elements wherein property either does not exist or property is not matching a particular id.

Here is what I have so far. When I add the second condition about `not elemMatch` it is not working.

```
    bookLendingHistory = {
      $or: [
        { 'lendHistory.borrowerId': { $exists: false } },
        { 'lendHistory.borrowerId': { $not: { $elemMatch: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } } },
      ],
    };
```

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Can you post sample data set?

Comment: Do you want the that matches the id or that does not match the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `$not` or `$elemMatch`

I believe this should solve your problem:
`{'lendHistory.borrowerId':{ $ne: ObjectId("123456789012345678901234") } }`

This will give you all the documents that don't match the `ObjectId`, including the ones that don't have the field.